# Changing the font for printing

Tags: printing, dokuwiki

After upgrading DokuWiki to *Adora Belle*, the font used for printing has changed to something terrible (looks like Times New Roman).

I do my printing  using the browsers print command, i.e. *File > Print*. I have tried to print under Windows and Mac as well as different browsers, all with the same result.

I have not been able to find a setting in DokuWiki to change the font; is there one, or can I change some stylesheet to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I needed only to edit DokuWiki's `print.css` style sheet to change fonts. I had come this far with my research before asking the question but couldn't get it to work. This was because I changed the wrong instance of the `print.css` file; there are actually three of them in the wiki's installation directory. The correct one was `<wiki>/lib/tpl/dokuwiki/css`.